# How to fix CKEDITOR.cleanWord is not a function

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Hai I am using ckeditor 4.12.1 in my application. I need to copy and paste content from MS Word.I added "pastefromword" plugin and added configuration settings in config.js.But still it doesn't work.The following error hit
"CKEDITOR.cleanWord is not a function".

My config file

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';


config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';


config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

config.extraPlugins = 'pastefromword';
config.extraPlugins = 'clipboard';
config.extraPlugins = 'notification';
config.extraPlugins = 'toolbar';
config.extraPlugins = 'button';

config.pasteFromWordCleanupFile = 'plugins/pastefromword/filter/default.js';
config.pasteFromWordNumberedHeadingToList = true;
config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = true;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was caused by missing /plugins/pastetools/filter/common.js file on the server. The root cause was that this file was new after a CKEditor version upgrade and not included in the project. Consequently it was missing in deploy to staging and production environments. It was working fine for developers because the file was not missing in source control.

Comment: This fix worked for me. We are compacting JS for production in our project and the plugins "pastefromword" and "pastetools" have to be included because of their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As Tore mentioned, `pastetools` and other things like Advanced Content Filter were implemented to assist handling content. ([pastefromword docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/pastefromword.html))

Something to also note, the setting `pasteFromWordRemoveStyles` is for CKE versions older than 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a problem at ckeditor.js..
What worked for me was to remove the content of the function in line 16136:

```
 function l(a, f, e) {
        var h = CKEDITOR.cleanWord;
        h ? e() : (a = CKEDITOR.getUrl(a.config.pasteFromWordCleanupFile || f + "filter/default.js"), CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(a, e, null, !0));
        return !h
    }
```

Now just clean the content fo the function and leave it like that:

```
function l(a, f, e) {}
```

Pay attention that the filters you have added my not work.